# In HTTP 1.1, Content-Length = "Content-Length" ":" 1*DIGIT

Tags: http

In HTTP 1.1,  Content-Length    = "Content-Length" ":" 1*DIGIT
My question is how to understand "1*DIGIT"?

Does it mean any count of digits? Does it allow prefix 0, such as "00123"?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot.

So seems that HTTP doesn't restrict size of request or response, it allows to download/upload file with size >2GB, however a lot of server implementation will report error in case of file >2GB.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting RFC 2616:

> The character `*` preceding an element indicates repetition. The
>   full form is `<n>*<m>element` indicating at least  and at most
>    occurrences of element. Default values are 0 and infinity so
>   that `*(element)` allows any number, including zero; `1*element`
>   requires at least one; and `1*2element` allows one or two.